# How can I make this recursive Binary Search program exit and not crash if the number is not found?

Tags: c, recursion, crash, binary-search

How can I prevent this program from crashing if the value the user searched for is not found? (When I try to implement an if/else or count system, the program doesn't work correctly)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"
#include "genlib.h"
#define start 0
void bubble(int numbers[]);
int binary(int val, int numbers[], int low, int high);
void io(int numbers[]);
int size;
main()
{
    int result, search;
    printf("This program sorts and searches an array\n");
    printf("How many numbers would you like to sort and search?\n");
    size = GetInteger()-1;
    int numbers[size];
    printf("Enter the numbers\n");
    io(numbers);
    bubble(numbers);
    printf("Which number would you like to search for?\n");
    search = GetInteger();
    result = binary(search,numbers,start,size);
    printf("The number %d was found at index %d\n",search,result+1);
}

void io(int numbers[])
{
    int ink;
    for(ink=0;ink<=size;ink++)
    {
        numbers[ink] = GetInteger();
    }
}

void bubble(int numbers[])
{
    int first,second,count,swap;
    while(TRUE)
    {
        for(first=0,second=1,count=0;second<=size;first++,second++)
        {
            if(numbers[first]>numbers[second])
            {
                count++;
                swap = numbers[first];
                numbers[first]= numbers[second];
                numbers[second] = swap;
            }
        }
        if(count==0)break;
    }
}

int binary(int val, int numbers[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    mid = (low+high)/2;
    if(val==numbers[mid]||low>high) return mid;
    if(val>numbers[mid]) return(binary(val,numbers,mid,high));
    else if(val<numbers[mid]) return(binary(val,numbers,low,mid));
}
```

Comment: `for(ink=0;ink < size;ink++)` and `for(first=0,second=1,count=0;second < size;first++,second++)` ... for a start.

Comment: 'Write code, fix compile errors, test, fail, post on SO'.  There is a missing step...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to

```
size = GetInteger();
int numbers[size--];//change size to max index
//..

int binary(int val, int numbers[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low>high)//if not found!
        return -1;//check return value at main
    mid = (low+high)/2;
    if(val==numbers[mid]) return mid;
    if(val>numbers[mid]) return(binary(val,numbers,mid+1,high));
    else if(val<numbers[mid]) return(binary(val,numbers,low,mid-1));
}
```